# Why is can't this code's array identify and spit out max values greater than two digits

Tags: vba, list, ms-access, max

I've been using this piece of code in Access VBA to look at numeric values in a row (across 15 columns) and spit out the max value in that row. The problem is, max values greater than 99 are not included in the list, and as such, are omitted as the correct max value. Why and how can I fix it?

So example, maxoflist(1,2,99,182) would return 99 and not 182. Why?

Here is the code:

```
Function MaxOfList(ParamArray varValues()) As Variant
    Dim i As Integer        'Loop controller.
    Dim varMax As Variant 'Largest value found so far.

    varMax = Null           'Initialize to null

    For i = LBound(varValues) To UBound(varValues)
        If IsNumeric(varValues(i)) Or IsDate(varValues(i)) Then
            If varMax >= varValues(i) Then
                'do nothing
            Else
                varMax = varValues(i)
            End If
        End If
    Next    
    MaxOfList = varMax
End Function
```

Thanks!

Comment: if varMax is null, then nothing will be returned as iif accepts true, false or null. Is that where you're going with this?

Comment: With me `?maxoflist(1,2,99,182)` returns 182. Even `?maxoflist(1,2,182,99,234)` returns `234`.

Comment: So I'm feeding it column names, 15 column names. For exmaple, maxoflist(field1,field2,field3,field4,field5,field6,field7,...,field15), and all fields return numbers. I'll make sure my values are in val() funciton. Anything else that could be a problem?

Comment: Can you put a screenshot of the designer view of the table with the names?

Comment: Or write `debug.print varValues(i)` before the first condtion , to see which enters.

Comment: So puting maxoflist(val(field1),...val(field15)) worked. So it must have been that the last three fields which could have values greater than 99 were converted into a different data type from the first 12 fields...weird

Answer (score 0):

Selecting the max value of a list is quite a trivial task and your code is achieving it well. The problem should be somewhere else. Something like this should get you started in the debug process:

```
Function MaxOfList(ParamArray varValues()) As Variant
    Dim i As Integer        'Loop controller.
    Dim varMax As Variant 'Largest value found so far.

    varMax = Null           'Initialize to null

    For i = LBound(varValues) To UBound(varValues)
        If IsNumeric(varValues(i)) Or IsDate(varValues(i)) Then
            If varMax >= varValues(i) Then
                'do nothing
            Else
                varMax = varValues(i)
            End If
        Else
            Debug.Print varValues(i)
            Stop
        End If
    Next
    MaxOfList = varMax
End Function
```

Once you get a value, which does not pass the `If IsNumeric(varValues(i)) Or IsDate(varValues(i)) Then` it should `Stop`. Continue by pressing <kbd>F5</kbd>.

Comment: yeah the problem is that integers greater than 99 become a different data type than those <100. But if I explicitly define all integers with a val() function, then I don't have that problem anymore. I guess the question is why integers >99 are turning into some other data type...

Comment: @72444ajax - "integers greater than 99 become a different data type than those <100" - this sounds like a giant issue for MS Access and I sincerely hope that you are wrong somewhere.